# How do I apply CodecOptions to a mongoengine collection to get tzinfo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, bson

Using a mongoengine `Document`, when I load a `DateTimeField` from mongo, it lacks `tzinfo`. Our application by policy wants all datetimes to have `tzinfo`.

When I save to mongo, I know that pymongo does the correct and predictable thing wrt timezones; if it is naive, it is stored as a UTC time, if it has a timezone, it is converted to UTC and then stored as UTC time. All good so far.

When I load, though, `DateTimeField` always gives me a naive `datetime`. I know that this `datetime` is in UTC, so I could add the `tzinfo` if I wanted, but I'd have to do this in dozens of places in my application, and it's a guarantee of future timezone bugs, *unless* I use a custom field type (see example below).

Referencing: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/datetimes.html I know that pymongo supports putting the `tzinfo` onto the object as it arrives from the database. I also know that I can do this myself, as the following minimal example shows. The `DateTimeTZField` adds `tzinfo` in `to_python`.

```
from datetime import datetime

from mongoengine import connect, Document, fields

from pytz import timezone

def utcnowTZ():
    return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTF'))

class DateTimeTZField(fields.DateTimeField):
    """
    This seems like a hack. I would like to use CodecOptions instead
    """
    def to_python(self, value):
        converted = super(DateTimeTZField, self).to_python(value)
        return converted.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))

class Thing(Document):
    dtTZ = DateTimeTZField(default=utcnowTZ)
    dtXX = fields.DateTimeField(default=utcnowTZ)

connect(host="mongodb://localhost/datetimewithtz")
Thing.objects().delete()

t1 = Thing()
print '%r.dtXX (default): %s' % (t1, t1.dtXX)
print '%r.dtTZ (default): %s' % (t1, t1.dtTZ)
t1.save()
print 'saved %r' % t1.id; print
t1 = Thing.objects(id=t1.id).first()
print 'reloaded %r' % t1.id
print '%r.dtXX (loaded ): %s' % (t1, t1.dtXX)
print '%r.dtTZ (loaded ): %s' % (t1, t1.dtTZ)
```

**Without** replacing DateTimeField throughout my application, **is there a way to use bson CodecOptions** to make this apply globally to all DateTimeFields: *when loaded from the database, they should have tzinfo attached*?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
connect(...,  tz_aware=True,...)
```

the parameter will be forwarded to `MongoClient(..., tz_aware=True, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that mongoengine doesn't support *per-model* `codec_options`. If it did, they should be part of the `opts` dictionary [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/f35034b989d83cae883c37524d86711a4014046f/mongoengine/document.py#L201).

However, PyMongo defaults to the Database's `codec_options` when the Collection doesn't have any of it's own, and you can set these by manually calling `register_connection` in your application before you make any requests to the DB.

In your example above you should pass the `codec_options` like this:

```
with_timezone = CodecOptions()
connect(host="mongodb://localhost/datetimewithtz", codec_options=with_timezone)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer, I'll be back once I've tried this. I'm going to be instantiating CodecOptions(tz_aware=True), let me know if that's not right.